Short story about an injured alien lifeform that fell to an island on modern day Earth and was unable to communicate with humans
It was a short story. I believe it's by Alfred van Vogt.
Some sentient lifeform (maybe it is a huge robot) fell to an ocean on modern day Earth, escaping from war. Its vision is based on radiation, so this creature does not see water and decided it fell on some mountain (it is the base of an island, in fact). The creature thinks it is in an uninhabited desert.
It crawls to the top of this "mountain" and discover humans. Trying to establish contact, the creature is sending packages of directed gamma radiation (that is the normal way for it to communicate), killing humans all over.
Humans are shocked and used a nuke, trying to kill this strange creature. But the creature considers the nuclear explosion as "food" that is enough to repair its damage. Still understanding nothing, the creature leaves Earth.

Can you tell us where and when you read this story. See here for other things that could be useful.

Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. That is not a censure, but rather part of our policy for when the accepted answer to a story-identification question is identical to another accepted answer. You will still receive points for upvotes and people can comment. Don't forget to formally accept by clicking on the checkmark to gain a few more points.

Your description, changing a few particulars, sounds like "Dormant", by A. E. van Vogt, which first appeared in the November 1948 issue of Startling Stories.

The monster of the story was named Iilah. Iilah was a robotic weapon that came to Earth during a prehistoric alien war, and was deactivated by an enemy weapon. Iilah was four hundred feet long and one hundred feet wide, and to humans looked like a two-million ton rock. (The first Americans to arrive at the island are puzzled to find the giant rock atop the island's mountain, as such a rock did not appear in their reconnaissance photos.)  Iilah lay in the lagoon of a Pacific island for millions of years, until fallout from the early atomic weapons woke it into an amnesiac state - the monster knows it's supposed to do something, but can't remember what. Iilah cannot see water, so when an America navy ship arrives at the island after World War II, the monster perceives the ship as levitating. Iilah assumes the ship to be some type of being. Iilah's attempts at communicating with the ship kills many crewmen with hard radiation. When the ship fires back with cannons, Iilah first assumes the attack to be an attempt at communication, but the damage the monster receives changes its mind and it moves into the water and rams the ship onto the beach. Iilah then goes on a rampage across the island, killing hundreds of men - but their deaths were not intentional. Iilah did not even know that the men existed as human bodies were invisible to the monster, being mostly water. As a last resort the military decided to kill the monster with a nuclear weapon; as the bomber approached, Iilah sensed the weapon as something like itself. The explosion provided Iilah with enough energy to overcome his amnesia and recall his purpose on Earth. The monster did not then depart, but destroyed the Earth. The story's final line reads, 'Even if Iilah had known that it was not the same war that had raged ten thousand million centuries before, he would have had no choice but to do as he did. Robot atom bombs do not make up their own minds.'

Exactly! Thanks a lot.

@user185929: You can formally accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].
